# AWS CLI - Create Lambda With Public ECR Url Keeps Erroring

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, github-actions, amazon-ecr

I am using GitHub Actions to first check if a lambda exists and and if it doesn't create one and just inject a placeholder container from NGINX the next step in the pipeline will build and replace the contaier in the lambda. I log in to ECR so I am creditialed but my pipeline errors every time saying the url is invlaid

Code:

```yaml
    - name: Add Lambda
      id: lamda-managment
      shell: bash
      env:
        ECR_REGISTRY: ${{ steps.login-ecr.outputs.registry }}
        ECR_REPOSITORY: ${{env.ECR_REPOSITORY}}
        IMAGE_TAG: ${{env.ENV}}
      run: |
        aws lambda get-function --function-name ${{env.FUNCTION_NAME}} || \
        aws lambda create-function \
          --function-name ${{env.FUNCTION_NAME}} \
          --role arn:aws:iam::${{env.AWS_ACCOUNT_ID}}:role/lambda-ex \
          --package-type Image \
          --code ImageUri=public.ecr.aws/nginx/nginx:alpine-slim
```

Error:

```
when calling the CreateFunction operation: Source image public.ecr.aws/nginx/nginx:alpine-slim is not valid.
```

Comment: From the documentation: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/images-create.html It mentions that the docker image has to be in an ECR repo in the same region as the Lambda function. This leads me to think it has to be in a private ECR repo. There is no mention of being able to create a Lambda function directly from a public ECR image in the documentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to push my own nginx image to my private ECR